# Unable to Hide a column in Excel 97-2003 workbook

Tags: vba, excel, hide

I am trying to hide a column A1 in my sheet using vba. But am getting a error **"unable to set hidden property of range class"**

Here is my code:

```
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Project").Activate
   ActiveSheet.Unprotect password

   Dim cmt As comment
   Dim iRow As Integer

   For iRow = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
      Set cmt = Cells(iRow, 1).comment
         If Not cmt Is Nothing Then

            Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = Cells(iRow, 1).comment.Text
            Cells(iRow, 1).comment.Delete
         Else
         MsgBox "No Comments"
         End If
   Next iRow

   MsgBox ActiveSheet.ProtectionMode

   ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Select

   Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Am getting error in the line

```
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

I have included **MsgBox** to check whether the sheet is protected and is there any comment available in the cells of that column.

**1st MsgBox returns as No Comments and 2nd returns as false.**

So the sheet is not protected and comment is also not present.

Confused on why getting the error eventhough.

Please help me out

**UPDATE:**

I have changed my code like this:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Project").Activate

    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim rangeToTest As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim c As Range

    lRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rangeToTest = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
        For Each c In rangeToTest

            For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                sh.Delete
            Next sh
        Next c

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

And it worked. But I have added comments to other column headers which i get on hovering mouse over the cell. Am not getting the comments now..

Does deleting shapes have something to do with comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually  i have added comments to other columns in my sheet. Comments come under activesheet.shapes so due to that i am unable to hide the column. Once I have set the placement for that it works perfectly

This code does the trick:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Activate

Dim sh As Shape
Dim rangeToTest As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim c As Range

lRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rangeToTest = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    For Each c In rangeToTest

        For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            sh.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        Next sh
    Next c

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `entirecolumn` and hidden properties directly on columns, those properties works for Range() object only. Take `Range("A1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`

Thanks
Nag

Comment: changed the line like this:

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

But still same error

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line also

ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Select

Answer (score 0):

Your code just works fine for me?? I'm in excel 2010, maybe you're not. Plugged it in as is and password protected the sheet as well. Comments or not made no difference, it will hide it whatever.

Comment: Was supposed to be a comment but couldn't place it anywhere.

Comment: I have added autofilter to the column which i am trying to hide... will that be an issue?

Comment: No. Did you test it taking it from a sheet having no protection and comments? And only then adding a password and comments consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1. [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)
2. Don't use `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))` to find the last row. See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) link on how to find the last row.

Is this what you are trying (UNTESTED)?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cmt As Comment
    Dim iRow As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim Password As String

    '~~> Change as applicable
    Password = "Blah Blah"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project")

    With ws
        .Unprotect Password

        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For iRow = 1 To lRow
            Set cmt = .Cells(iRow, 1).Comment
            If Not cmt Is Nothing Then
                .Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = .Cells(iRow, 1).Comment.Text
                .Cells(iRow, 1).Comment.Delete
            Else
                'MsgBox "No Comments"
                Debug.Print "No Comments"
            End If
        Next iRow

        .Columns(1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        .Protect Password
    End With
End Sub
```